# Typescript with AMD static variables are resetting

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I am running into an issue where static variables inside my classes are sometimes resetting back to their default values. Ex:

```
class Moveable extends DivElement {
    static INSTANCES: Moveable[] = [];

    constructor(id: string, parent: HTMLElement) {
        super(id, parent);

        Moveable.INSTANCES.push(this);
    }
}

export default Moveable;
```

Whenever I create a new Moveable instance it gets added to the static INSTANCES variable. However, occasionally it will reset back to an empty array.

Looking at the network tab I am noticing that moveable.js is being loaded twice which would cause this issue. How/why is it being loaded twice? I am using require.js and compiling the typescript with --module amd

Comment: You wrote that you're using `require.js` and you are loading AMD modules, so I've inferred that you're using RequireJS and added the tag. This being said, your question is currently incomplete. I've used RequireJS for years. Modules are singletons: it does not matter if you require a module once, twice, 300 times. RequireJS will load only one instance of the module. This being said, it is definitely possible to shoot yourself in the foot by misconfiguring RequireJS or misusing it. You should show your RequireJS configuration and how you load your code in the browser.

Comment: @Louis thank you for your response. I looked over the RequireJs configuration and noticed that if a baseurl isn't specified it will set it to the data-main attribute if one is given. I was using the attribute but it did not point to the root. Changing the baseurl to '.' fixed everything